# while running batch file command prompt window blink

Tags: batch-file

I am running my batch file inside my code, it's working fine, I just want to know is there anyway I can stop the blinking of command prompt window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using some VBScript like this.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("C:\yourbatchfile.bat"), 0, True
```